# IIS 8.5 virtual directory not serving default document

Tags: iis, default, iis-8, virtual-directory

Seems like with the default settings, a newly created virtual directory does not serve the default files it contains. How can I enable this?

```
app <- .net app available at domain.com/

   /virtualdir/index.htm  <- default file in a virtual directory
```

I would like to make it possible for requests to `domain.com/virtualdir` to serve `domain.com/virtualdir/index.htm`

Currently `domain.com/virtualdir/index.htm` works as desired, but `domain.com/virtualdir` returns a 404.

Any ideas? I think I might need to add something to a webconfig file in virtualdir but not quite sure what. index.htm is already in the list of default documents.

Detailed Error Information:

Module     ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    ek*
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/virtualdir/
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\extras\virtualdir\
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

Comment: You should have actually got 403.14 if default document is not set. What kind of application is it webforms or MVC ?

Comment: The host folder is a part of a web forms application.

Comment: Then it should work if you have a default document. You can probably try moving index.htm high up in the hierarchy for the virtual directory and see or remove it and add it back. Also I am surprised on 404 . Any URL Rewrite rule or any specific re-directions ?

Comment: @RaviA. Index.htm is directly under virtualdir. I haven't added any rules to virtualdir, just created it.

Comment: ya all the existing configurations from parent gets inherited to sub directories. That's only a check as configuring default document should work and I am surprised as you are getting 404. So any error pages configured or something like that? Rest waht ever you did should have worked.

Comment: What configuration should I check and where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123561/discussion-between-ravi-a-and-aaandre).

Comment: The discussion in chat contains the answer for this use: "I was able to make the default file load by copying the `web.config` from a virtual application."